# How to efficiently count the number of times a bubble sort would iterate?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, complexity-theory, mergesort

A typical bubble sort (of complexity N^2) looks something like this (from Wikipedia):

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
n = length(A)
repeat
    swapped = false
    for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
        if A[i-1] > A[i] then
            swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
            swapped = true
```

How would one determine the number of times the outer loop iterates in less than **O(N^2)**? (shown below, it's too slow):

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
n = length(A)
count = 0
repeat
    count += 1
    swapped = false
    for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
        if A[i-1] > A[i] then
            swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
            swapped = true
```

Comment: "Efficient" and "Bubble sort" do not go in the same sentence, but I'm confused as to how a counter is "too slow". Adding one to an integer is one of the fastest things you can do on a CPU.

Comment: @tadman, I don't want to implement a bubble sort, I want to find out how many times a bubble sort would have iterated.

Comment: You're doing that in your pseudo code and unless you can explain why that would be "too slow", that's your answer. If you want to compute the worst case scenario, it's n*(n-1) times for any given list of size *n*. The best case scenario is just *n* times, so in practice the value will be somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Why do I have to explain why I don't want an answer with complexity n^2? I just want to find a way to solve this problem without actually implementing a bubble sort.

Comment: Bubble sort is already n^2, adding a single operation to each iteration doesn't change that complexity. It has zero impact on the algorithm's characteristics.

Comment: I realize that what you're saying is true, but you misunderstand my question. I'm not implementing a bubble sort!

Comment: This is why this kind of question is problematic on Stack Overflow, it's not concrete code, just hypothetical code. To keep it on-topic you need to be dealing with an actual implementation in a particular language so we can discuss any actual performance problems, not theoretical ones. You'll also need to be specific about what this code should do, and what sort of input you expect it to handle and output that should produce.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration will shift the largest element to the end of the array (let's go left-to-right); each smaller element will move left at most 1 location.  The number of outer loops needed is the maximum displacement of any number in that direction.

In more detailed terms, you need to find the element of the array with the greatest number of larger elements to its left.  That quantity ("greatest number") is your answer.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I understand your approach. However, won't this also be O(n^2)? Or am I mistaken. Here's my thought process:

Loop _x_ through the entire list. Sum up the number of values from 0 to _x_ that are larger than _x_, and take the maximum of those sums.

Comment: The straightforward approach you outline is, indeed, **O(n^2)**.  However, the problem is not inherently that complex.  Think inductively: when you are at element 6, having processed the first 5 elements, how can you use the existing information to shorten your current processing?  When you process one element, can you shorten the processing of future elements?  There are applicable string-processing algorithms that "magically" reduce **O(n^2)** algorithms through *not* throwing out knowledge gained in earlier steps.